# Regex Validators in asp.net - validate all strings except those with a specific character

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, validation

I'd like to use a `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` where the `ValidatorExpression` is a regex that matches all strings that do not contain an ampersand.  Google fu didn't yield much, but I'm sure it's probably not too complicated.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
   ID="StringValidator1"
   runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="textBox1"
   ValidationExpression="???"
   Display="Dynamic"
   ErrorMessage="String cannot contain ampersands"
   ValidationGroup="Group1"
/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
ValidationExpression = "^[^&]*$"
```

matches any string that doesn't contain an ampersand.

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
[^&]*  # Any number of characters that are not ampersands
$      # End of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will be

```
^[^&]+$
```

Means everything except `&`